# Prevent redirect to page/page when reserved term 'name' in $_POST when value is a page/post title

Tags: redirect, query-string

I'm using a particular payment gateway which includes in their payment response the parameter 'name'. I'm aware this is a [reserved term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) which shouldn't be used. Unfortunately, I have no control over the posted data.

I've produced the following function which renames the 'name' parameter and then redirects to the requested page (instead of showing a 404).

```
function redirect() {

    if ( is_404() && isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['instId']) ) {

        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params); 
        $params['fullname'] = $params['name'];
        unset($params['name']);

        $protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?').'?'.http_build_query($params);

        wp_redirect( $protocol.$location ); exit;

    }

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect');
```

However, if the value of the 'name' parameter is a (partial) match for an existing page or post title then Wordpress redirects to the page/post *before* my function runs. I've tried hooking into various actions to get the function to run earlier, but with no effect - is there a way round this without undesired side-effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually suggest an alternative approach - remove the function that causes the redirect in the first place:

```
function wpse_227033_disable_name_redirect() {
    if ( is_404() && isset( $_GET['name'], $_GET['instID'] ) )
        remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_227033_disable_name_redirect' );
```

I've used the `wp` hook which runs pretty much just before `template_redirect`. Remember you'll need to clear your browser cache before testing (those redirects are `301`'s).

Comment: Does this have any side-effects? I'm guessing that it disables redirects for guessing the correct destination for mistyped urls.

Comment: The only side effect is if a) it's a 404 b) the `name` and `instID` parameters exist and c) WordPress _could_ redirect to similar matching page, then it won't.